# Solid of Revolution About y=2

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume of the solid of revolution bounded by $y=x^4$ and $y=1$ rotated about $y=2$.

Here's my attempt:

$\pi\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(2-x^4)^2dx$

$\pi\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(4-4x^4+x^8)dx$

$\pi(\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(4)dx-4\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(x^4)dx+\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(x^8)dx)$

$\pi(8-4(\frac{2}{5})+\frac{2}{9})$

$\frac{298\pi}{45}$

But the book says $\frac{208\pi}{45}$

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: There is an extra cylinders worth of volume that you've included. This is the inside of the "washer" if you've heard of the washer method. In other words, you need to subtract the volume that happens when you rotate the region between y=1 and y=2 around y=2 since that's not included in your region. Does that help? (looking at the graph might help too!)

Comment: @emma Yes, I have heard of the washer method. Were my bounds wrong or was the integrand wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

What you are looking for

[image]

Your answer

[image]

\begin{align*}
\text{Volume }&=\text{Volume of the solid without the "hole"}-\text{Volume of the cylinder }\\
&=\pi\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1(2-x^4)^2dx-\pi\displaystyle\int_{-1}^11dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Would it be: $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}(2-x^4)^2dx - \displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 1dx$

Comment: Also, what program did you use to create that?

Comment: Wolfram Mathematica 7.0